# Specify date range in a shiny app based on another data frame input

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app below in which I want to be able to select the data range based on the choice of "INT" or "DOM" from the checkbox group. But I cannot make it work. I get an error when im trying to use `min` and `max`.
I recreated my data frame with:

```
OriginId = c("INT", "DOM", "INT","DOM") 
RequestedDtTm = c("2017-01-16 16:43:33
", "2017-01-17 16:43:33
", "2017-01-18 16:43:33
","2017-01-19 16:43:33") 
testdata = data.frame(OriginId,RequestedDtTm)



    ## ui.R ##
    library(shinydashboard)

    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody()
    )

    library(shinydashboard)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),

      ## Sidebar content
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
          menuItem("Change View", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
        )
      ),

      ## Body content
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # First tab content

          # Second tab content
          tabItem(tabName = "widgets",

                  fluidRow(
                    box(title="Histogram 1",width = 12,
                    column(4,

                      checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                                         choices = list("Show Domestic" = "DOM", "Show International" = "INT"),
                                         selected = "DOM")
                    ),
                    column(4,
                           uiOutput("dt1")

                    ),
                    column(4,

                      numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = 1)
                    )
                  ))


          )

        )
      )
    )
#server.r
    server <- function(input, output) {



      output$dt1<-renderUI({
      dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                     label = 'Date range',
                     start = min(subset(testdata[,2],testdata$OriginId %in% input$checkGroup2)), end = max(subset(testdata[,2],testdata$OriginId %in% input$checkGroup2))
      )
      })

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have the error message: `‘min’ not meaningful for factors`?

If yes, it indicates you're trying to take the `min()` of a factor, which is not allowed.

To solve this on your example data, you could do `testdata = data.frame(OriginId,RequestedDtTm, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

If your real data actually has factors, you could wrap them in `as.character()` before calling `min()`, like `min(as.character(subset(........)))`.

Same goes for `max()` of course.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `as.POSIXct()`.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail to your answer to make it helpful for others that have the same problem?